# Can't get the id of friends using facebook sdk for ios

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sdk, friend

Hi)Please can anybody help me? I need to get user's friends id from facebook. I saw this method on facebook "me/friends". Using their Graph API Expolorer I get this result:

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 1
  }
}
```

I recived only the count of my friends. But how can i get friend id?

Comment: that's not possible since April 2014 and their new Graph API version unless you use the **Invitable Friends API** (for which you also need a _Canvas_ app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API, `/me/friends` will **only** return those friends which are also using the same app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> The `/me/friends` endpoint no longer includes the full list of a person's friends. Instead, it now **returns the list of that person's friends who are also using your app**.

Comment: Can I see hoe this works in Graph API Explore? and i can't see id of friends?

Comment: What do you mean? With version >=v2.0, **this is no longer possible** as stated in the docs!

Comment: I mean i want to get something like this:
{data:{1111,22222,3333}} where 1111 - id of my friend I need to know who from my friend use my app

Comment: You'll start seeing results once at least one of your friends gave permissions to the same app.

Comment: You mean that I can't see the result using GRAPH API Explore?Please can you say how I can to check this method?

Comment: I already wrote everything, and linked the relevant docs. It's crystal clear

Comment: Thank you for help) But I don't understand how can I check this method. And how can I get list of id?

Comment: **It's only possible to receive the ids if your friends use the same app! And as the Graph Explorer is an app as well, you won't see any results as long as your friends didn't use it as well**

Comment: Thank you)It's work)I ask my friend to use GRAPH API Explorer and then make the request and it work)))))Thank you for help)